# 'Exists Condition' for dynamic pattern in Azure Data Factory Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory in which a data flow is used. In this dataflow I want to compare two sources, using the 'Exsits' transformation.
Both sources have identical column names. Only datarows in source1 that doesn't exist in source2 should be stored in Sink. The problem comes while configuring the Exits conditions. As I want to use the same pipeline for many datasets I want to use the custom expression field and implement late binding to compare the required columns in both sources. So I created an array input parameter ($primaryKeys) that holds the columns that needs to be compared in both the sources. Here is where I get stuck :

[image: Dataflow Diagram]

The expression that gives an error:

[image: Exists Condition]

Any suggestions how I can get the dynamic pattern in the expression here to work?

Comment: From where are you getting the value for the parameter `primitiveKeys`?

Comment: From an Az SQL table.

Comment: So, the columns specified in the `primitiveKeys` exist in both SAPSource and SQLSource?

Comment: Yes exactly. They exists in both sources.

Answer (score 1):

- I was able to achieve your requirement using 2 dataflows instead of one where I have used one dataflow to build the custom expression and the other to implement your exists logic.
- I have taken the `primitiveKeys` array parameter in dataflow where I am passing static value from pipeline for demonstration.

[image]

- In the first dataflow, with the above array parameter, take any dataset as source. Create a derived column transformation with the dynamic value as `toString(reduce(map($cols,concat('source1@',#item,' == source2@',#item)),'true() ',#acc+' && '+#item,#result))`. The source1 and source2 are the left and right stream names that I will be applying `exists` transformation on.

[image]

- Now, we need this value. So, I have used cache sink and writing the output to activity output.
- In the second dataflow, I have created a string parameter `custom_expr` for which I pass the value generated above.

[image]

- Now in the dataflow where we use custom expression, I have used the dynamic content as `toBoolean(expr(toString($custom_expr)))`.

This will give the results as desired.  The following are output images for reference.

- Source 1 data preview:

[image]

- Source 2 data preview:

[image]

- Does not exist result:

[image]

- The JSON for first dataflow:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText6",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     cols as string[] (['a','b'])",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as string,",
                "          first_name as string,",
                "          date as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(tp = toString(reduce(map($cols,concat('source1@',#item,' == source2@',#item)),'true() ',#acc+' && '+#item,#result))) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- The JSON for second dataflow:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText5",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                },
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText6",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source2"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "exists1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     custom_expr as string ('true()  && source1@id == source2@id && source1@first_name == source2@first_name')",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as string,",
                "          first_name as string,",
                "          date as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as string,",
                "          first_name as string,",
                "          date as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source2",
                "source1, source2 exists(toBoolean(expr(toString($custom_expr))),",
                "     negate:true,",
                "     broadcast: 'both')~> exists1",
                "exists1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**  The only hardcoded values in the above when you try to replicate this would be the left and right stream names to build the expression.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me though. One source is parquet and the other is SQL DB. The columns to be compared are present in both sources even then I get the error  : 
Job failed due to reason: at Exists 'exists1'(Line 1/Col 0): Column xyz not found. The stream is either not connected or column is unavailable.  When I enter a specific schema or import projections for a particular Table/Dataset it works. But then it doesn't serve the purpose as I need dynamic schemas depending on the input dataset.

Comment: According to the MSFT documentation, for the custom_expr we need to use byName for late binding of columns.  I will try that and see.

Comment: Are you using dynamic content for the source name in dataflow? Try using the above approach with inline datasets if possible.